# Veins Add Polygon to SUMO GUI

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am simulating a scenario where I want to add and/or delete polygon dynamically. However, when I tried to add a polygon, the system generates me below error;

```
<!> ASSERT: Condition 'result == RTYPE_OK' does not hold in function 'query' at veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:119 -- in module (TraCIDemo11p) RSUExampleScenario.node[1].appl (id=14), at t=1.1s, event #12
```

I debug the code and I see that the  TraciConnection does not return the RTYPE_OK. If I remove the assert statement, the code works fine. However, I want to learn the logic behind this.

I also see that the SUMO console give an error message. The code that I used to add polygon is;

```
  traci->addPolygon(polyId, polyType, color, filled, layer, points);
```

Sumo: 0.32 Omnet: 5.4.1 Veins: 4.7

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am a starter on GUI related things. Sorry if the question does not make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely SUMO refuses to add the polygon you requested. Maybe the ID you chose already exists in the simulation.

To find out why SUMO complains, you can change its source code to include debug output -- or you can run SUMO in a debugger.

To run SUMO in a debugger, the simplest solution is to switch from using `TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd` to `TraCIScenarioManager` (probably by changing `veins/nodes/Scenario.ned`) and launching SUMO in a debugger manually (e.g. by running `lldb sumo -- --remote-port 9999 -c erlangen.sumo.cfg`)